# pfsense more than 2 isp provider

Tags: isp, pfsense

is it **possible** to bridge **more than *2 isp*** provider using *pfsense*?
what **router or device can bridge 2 or more isp providers** in a router?
i am planning to bridge at lease ***5 isp*** providers to create a very good internet connection, what can i do to **link all 5 providers** in **1 router**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, pfSense can set up outgoing load balancing with any number of WAN ports. I successfully used it with 7 internet connections a few years ago.

Configure each WAN port as a gateway, and then put them all in the same gateway group. Then use a firewall rule to direct all traffic to that gateway group, instead of a specific WAN port.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer... Assuming you want to simply join two ISPs without using the failover or load balancing, so you can use the bandwidth between two subnets, will this same method work? I suppose you wouldn't add the two two gateways to a group in this case?

Comment: @nicorellius I'm not quite sure I follow. You're either load balancing for maximum utilization of both connections, or doing failover in case one connection goes down. I don't understand what other method/reason you'd have for two uplinks.

Comment: Maybe I don't know the meaning of load balancing in this sense... I get the fail over method with the gateway groups. But I was asking about if you have two ISPs and you want each to deliver service to a different subnet (eg, 192.168.50.x/24 and 192.168.55.x/24) via one pfSense firewall/router (with their own interfaces) to maximize performance and speeds. I'm still new to networking, so it's likely I'm not thinking about these things correctly. My apologies in advance.

Comment: @nicorellius Ah, that makes sense now. Yes, I think you can do that with pfSense, but I have not personally tried it. Just create a gateway & gateway group for each WAN (ISP) interface, and then route each subnet to a different gateway group.

Comment: I have a situation where we purchased an additional Internet connection bundled in with the phone service. I thought since I have a lot of traffic transferring large files (routine 10-50 GB transfers in and out of the subnet), I could isolate the sales department on their own ISP and route traffic with the existing pfSense firewall. It'd be cool if I could do what I mentioned above and use load balancing and fail over if either ISP goes down. Not sure if this is possible but I'm researching it now. Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: @ Darth Android - do think it is possible to set up two subnets as I've described above and implement load balancing and fail over?

Comment: @nicorellius It should be possible, yes, but you might have to do some hacking around with shell scripts.